# Adding elements into 5 ArrayList with 3 threads: the sum of the arraylist's size is always different

Tags: java, multithreading

The `Company` class contains 5 ArrayList, that I'm trying to update with 3 threads. The `addToWorkers()` method gets the type of the `Employee` subclasses, and adds them to the corresponding array. I'm using the LazyHolder class because my Company singleton instance has to be static, and it should provide synchronization.

```
public class Company {

    private static class LazyHolder {
        private static final Company INSTANCE = new Company();
}

    private volatile List<ProjectLeader> projectLeaders = new ArrayList<>();
    private volatile List<ConsultantLeader> consultantLeaders = new ArrayList<>();
    private volatile List<DeveloperLeader> developerLeaders = new ArrayList<>();
    private volatile List<DeveloperWorker> developerWorkers = new ArrayList<>();
    private volatile List<ConsultantWorker> consultantWorkers = new ArrayList<>();

    private Company() {
    }

    public static Company getInstance() {
        return LazyHolder.INSTANCE;
    }

    public synchronized <T extends Employee> void addToWorkers(T t) {
        Position p = t.getPosition();
        switch (p) {
            case DEVELOPER_WORKER: Company.getInstance().developerWorkers.add((DeveloperWorker) t);
                break;
            case DEVELOPER_LEADER: Company.getInstance().developerLeaders.add((DeveloperLeader) t);
                break;
            case CONSULTANT_WORKER: Company.getInstance().consultantWorkers.add((ConsultantWorker) t);
                break;
            case CONSULTANT_LEADER: Company.getInstance().consultantLeaders.add((ConsultantLeader) t);
                break;
            case PROJECT_LEADER: Company.getInstance().projectLeaders.add((ProjectLeader) t);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The `Runner` class implements the `Runnable` interface:

```
public class Runner implements Runnable {

    private Random random = new Random();
    private Position[] positions = Position.values();

    final Position randomPosition(){
        return positions[random.nextInt(positions.length)];
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 350; i++) {
            Position p = randomPosition();
            switch (p) {
                case PROJECT_LEADER:
                Company.getInstance().addToWorkers(new ProjectLeader(p, "projectLeader"));
                    break;
                case DEVELOPER_LEADER:
                Company.getInstance().addToWorkers(new DeveloperLeader(p, "developerLeader"));
                    break;
                case CONSULTANT_LEADER:
                    Company.getInstance().addToWorkers(new ConsultantLeader(p, "consultantLeader"));
                    break;
                case DEVELOPER_WORKER:
                Company.getInstance().addToWorkers(new DeveloperWorker(p, "developerWorker"));
                    break;
                case CONSULTANT_WORKER:
                Company.getInstance().addToWorkers(new ConsultantWorker(p, "consultantWorker"));
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since all the List type variables are `volatile` and the method I'm using is `synchronized` I'd expect, that if I run my main method, and get the sum of the size of each array, I'd get exactly 1050 each time, but I dont, it's always between 1000-1100, or sometimes `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`:

```
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();
    try {
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        t3.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(Company.getInstance().getConsultantLeaders().size() +
            Company.getInstance().getDeveloperWorkers().size() +
            Company.getInstance().getConsultantLeaders().size() +
            Company.getInstance().getDeveloperLeaders().size() +
            Company.getInstance().getProjectLeaders().size());
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Where is thrown the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`?

Comment: Runner class, void() method last add in the switch-case

Comment: Are you sure you've added all the `Position` values in the `swith/case` of `Company`? You can add a `default` to look if there are some warnings.

Comment: Everything is there, I'm using an enum for that, and only have 5 values

Comment: I am not sure if adding volatile to an ArrayList acts as you expect. I would say that the volatile variable is the reference to the list, but not the list itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your logic there is no reason to make your lists visible for all threads,

```
public synchronized <T extends Employee> void addToWorkers(T t)
```

is enough to make it thread safe, but with this way there is no point to use multithreading.

I suggest you to define your lists like this :

```
private  List<ProjectLeader> projectLeaders = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
private  List<ConsultantLeader> consultantLeaders = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
private  List<DeveloperLeader> developerLeaders = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
private  List<DeveloperWorker> developerWorkers = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
private  List<ConsultantWorker> consultantWorkers = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
```

Now we can solve your real problem , this one is funny :)

Check your sum, you are not adding to consultantworkers to the sum, you are adding consultant leaders for twice :

```
 System.out.println(
        Company.getInstance().getConsultantLeaders().size() + // leaders
        Company.getInstance().getDeveloperWorkers().size() +
        Company.getInstance().getConsultantLeaders().size() +//this one must be workers 
        Company.getInstance().getDeveloperLeaders().size() +
        Company.getInstance().getProjectLeaders().size());
```

you need also workers ;)

Comment: I can't believe that I've added consultantWorkers twice.. it was driving me crazy, thank you!

Comment: @dmbdnr leaders* :)

Comment: yeah, that one! But I still don't get why did you changed the addToWorkers argument type to Integer. Can you explain it please?

Comment: I was testing with integers, let me revert back.